# How to create new skin for `DatePicker`, javafx

Tags: javafx

I want to create a new skin class for `DatePicker`. Following different instructions about how to do it, e.g [guigarage](http://www.guigarage.com/2012/11/custom-ui-controls-with-javafx-part-1/) the right way is to extend `SkinBase` and load new skin class by setting `-fx-skin` property to the skin class name, so i did, but I got this Error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: sample.myDatePickerSkin cannot be cast to com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.DatePickerSkin
  at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.DatePickerBehavior.onAutoHide(DatePickerBehavior.java:103)
```

and if you look at `DatePickerBehavior.java:103`:

```
@Override public void onAutoHide() {
        // when we click on some non-interactive part of the
        // calendar - we do not want to hide.
        DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker)getControl();
        DatePickerSkin cpSkin = (DatePickerSkin)datePicker.getSkin();
        cpSkin.syncWithAutoUpdate();
        // if the DatePicker is no longer showing, then invoke the super method
        // to keep its show/hide state in sync.
        if (!datePicker.isShowing()) super.onAutoHide();
    }
```

So did I do anything wrong? or I should also write `myDatePickerBehavior`?

Comment: Please note that  com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BaseSkin is not a public API.

Answer (score 1):

The official way to implement a Skin is to either

- extend [javafx.scene.control.SkinBase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SkinBase.html) (since JavaFX 8.0)

or

- implement [Skin](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Skin.html) directly.

com.sun.javafx.scene‌​.control.skin.BaseSki‌​n is not a published API.

Please note that with Java SE 9 and Jigsaw, [DatePickerSkin](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/9/rt/file/0f32ff067545/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/skin/DatePickerSkin.java) as well as the other default [skins](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/9/rt/file/0f32ff067545/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/skin) will become published APIs, AFAIK. Then it should be safe to extend them if it meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I should extend DatePickerSkin :

```
package sample;

import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.DatePickerSkin;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;

public class customDatePickerSkin extends DatePickerSkin {
    public customDatePickerSkin(DatePicker datePicker) {
        super(datePicker);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.DatePickerSkin is not a published API. AFAIK, the default Skins will become published API with Java SE 9 and Jigsaw: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/9/rt/file/0f32ff067545/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/skin